# how to get the return value of a javascript onClick function in php

Tags: javascript, php, yii

this must be stupid but I can't find a solution ...

I'm using yii framework and I have Menu with several links :

```
$this->menu=array(

    array('label'=>'Badges : De tous','url'=>array('genCarteVisite','idEvent'=>$evenement->Id_Evenements, 'boolPrint'=>'%'),'linkOptions'=>array( 'onclick' => 'javascript: OnClickButton();')),
    ... and other links ... 
);
```

and I have, for example, my little JS function :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function OnClickButton () {
    return confirm('Desirez vous indiquer a la BD que vous les avez imprimé?');

 }  
</script>
```

and I just want to get back the return value (true or false of my confirm box) in my controller action "genCarteVisite".
How can I do that?

thanks.

Comment: $_GET variable? you need to post more details

Comment: PHP executes on the request for the page. It is a server side language and cannot talk with the page's Javascript functions without something like AJAX.

Comment: You should post your data to the controller, read more here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: [OMG it's hard to make a clear comment !] something like        
     `function OnClickButton () {
  bool = confirm('Desirez vous indiquer a la BD que vous les avez imprimé?');
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/LayoutColloques/index.php/admin/genCarteVisite",
  data: bool,
 });    
 }`     
  in the view. (function called by the onclick event.)    
      and $_post['bool']  in the "genCarteVisite" action controller?      :s  it doesn't work because bool have Undefined Index. So, there is no Post data with bool name.

Comment: which detail you need user574632?  You have the link to my controller action, the onclick action, the JS called by the onclick. In my controller I just have my render because I can't get the var returned by my JS function.

Answer (score 0):

You actually shouldn't want to get the result of the confirm in your controller action.
If the user clicks "no" the url should not be triggered. Thus making the result obselete since the action should only be called if the user clicked "yes".

If your link redirects to the url without waiting for the cornfirm result you should add " return false;" behind "OnClickButton();" in the onclick attribute.

Comment: ok, it's not what I want, I don't have to use a confirm box maybe. I want to get the result of this action in my controller. If the user press yes, I have to make somes changes in the DB and show the page, if he press no, I just want to show the page. Any advice about how to proceed?

Comment: and if it's not possible, I'll make it by an other way. But event if I click on the cancel button, the controller action and then the next page is loaded. what I miss? My link ` array('label'=>'Badges : De tous','url'=>array('genCarteVisite',...),'linkOptions'=>array( 'onclick' => 'javascript: OnClickButton();')),`
and my JS `function OnClickButton () {
   if(confirm('En suivant ce liens, vous aller indiquer a la base de donnée que ces badges ont été imprimé. Voulez vous continuer?'))
     return true;
   else
    return false;
   return false;` thanks :)

Comment: When clicked yes it works right? triggering the function in the controller, but whatever the result of the confirm you want to refresh the gridview.

Then you should add $('#grid-id').yiiGridView('update'); After the onclick (confirm) function, not in the onclick function.
Also be sure to add id to the grid widget.

Comment: The return false; should also be outside of the onclick function preventing clicking cancel submitting.
'onclick' => 'javascript: OnClickButton(); $('#grid-id').yiiGridView('update'); return false;')

Comment: I don't know what do you want with your grid and I don't really understand. I don't have any grid. if I click on the link i go on an other page. so I don't update any grid :s

Comment: and if I add return false; after the OnClickButton(); it never load the page. event if I click on ok.